# bind to abstract types for c struct with idris

Tags: ffi, idris

I can not find how to treat this `typedef struct TF_Status TF_Status;` as abstract types and bind to that

the c function is `TF_Status* TF_NewStatus();`

```
data TF_Status
tfNewStatus : IO TF_Status 
tfNewStatus = foreign FFI_C "TF_NewStatus" (IO TF_Status)
```

http://docs.idris-lang.org/en/latest/reference/ffi.html

it complains that `When checking argument fty to function foreign: Can't find a value of type FTy FFI_C [] (IO TF_Status)`

Comment: What is the type of your C function? Why have you tagged both Haskell *and* Idris? What is a `TF_Status`? We need more information to answer this, please add it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TF_Status* TF_NewStatus();` returns a pointer to a `TF_Status` when called. So you only need

```
tfNewStatus : IO Ptr 
tfNewStatus = foreign FFI_C "TF_NewStatus" (IO Ptr)
```